# Empty response after a callback in form_alter

Tags: ajax, forms

I am trying to add a new field in a preexistent form and invoke a callback.
The response of the callback is alway an error with an empty response:

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
>   HTTP Result Code: 200
>   Debugging information follows.
>   Path: /system/ajax
>   StatusText: OK
>   ResponseText:

ResponseText is always empty.

The code I use in `my_form_form_alter()` is the following.

```
$form['country_views_exposed_form'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => t('Country'),
  '#options' => array(
    'sl'  => 'Select...',
    'au'  => 'Australia',
    'nz'  => 'New Zealand'
  ),
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => '__my_callback',
    'wrapper' => 'country-views-exposed-form-wrapper-',
    'method' => 'replace',
    'event' => 'change'
  ),
  '#attributes' => array('class' => 'views-exposed-widget')
);
```

All I put in `__my_callback()` produces the same result: I don't get a clean response.

```
function __my_callback(&$form, &$form_state) { 
  return $form['states_views_exposed_form'];
}
```

Comment: I don't know if that is a typo, but you return `$form['states_views_exposed_form']` in the AJAX callback and add `$form['country_views_exposed_form']` in the form.

Comment: @kiamaluno tnx but is not a typo.
when change 'country_views_exposed_form', 'states_views_exposed_form' is populated with new data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved.
Exposed form fields don't are the same of 'normal' form fields in drupal. I have applied the patch #46 listed here: http://drupal.org/node/1183418

Comment: Please mark your own answer as the correct answer so other people know that is the good answer without reading it.

Comment: ok, tnx for the suggestion